# Post request from postman seems to not be sending any json data

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I am trying to test my project out, and I am using postman right now to pass in some data:
I have set postman to "POST" to my local server through "body", and then I send the following:

```
{
    "name": "My Name"
}
```

Then, my server file post request is:

```
const express = require('express'),
router        = express.Router(),
gravatar      = require('gravatar'),
bcrypt        = require('bcryptjs'),
{check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');

// User Model
const User = require('../../models/User');

// @route       GET api/users
// @description Test Route
// @access      Public
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("User Route")
});

// @route       POST api/users
// @description Register User
// @access      Public
router.post('/', [
    check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please enter a valid email address').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password must contain at least 6 characters').isLength({min: 6})
], async (req, res) => {
    return res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I put in the res.send(req.body) to confirm anything is being sent to my server in general before I test any of the other code out, however, the res.send only returns: {} meaning that no json information has been sent to my server.  I know that the routes work because when I put in a GET request, it acts as expected.  Is there something obvious I am missing here?  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could be because it's async, have you tried removing that?

Comment: I tried removing the async, but that did not help fix the problem at all.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at the end: `return res.send(req.body);
}` should be `return res.send(req.body);
})` <-- with a bracket

Comment: Also, your GET route doesn't have curly brackets so that shouldn't work either

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.  I've made those changes to my code, and edited my question above.  Unfortunately it is still not working as I expected, the res.send(req.body) is sending an empty object.

Comment: Have you tried setting a key/value pair in Postman instead of raw JSON?

Comment: I just tested your route with raw JSON but without the 'check' array and it works fine

Comment: Are you able to add a screenshot of your Postman setup and response?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added the image in my post.  Even when I remove everything (including the async) and just have the res.send, it still sends just an empty object, whether I use json or key, value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my issue.  In the "Headers" I was missing the "Content-type - application/json".  After adding this is seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### the Reason for this problem is you need to use Body Parser##

---

Body-Parser used to process form data or handle JSON payloads in API requests. For instance, when building RESTful APIs, it ensures that the data sent by the client is correctly parsed and ready for processing by backend logic.

**the Solution :**
you should declare the json() function in top of your main file like as index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());  //the Solution

app.listen( 3000,()=>{
console.log("Server is Listening on Port 3000");
```

})